# FTDX3000D SWR Meter

Tags: yaesu, swr-meter

I just bought a Yaesu FTDX3000D and would like to see the SWR.  Is it possible to display the SWR on the FTDX3000D?  If so, what menu option would that be?  I'm not finding it.
I searched for this answer both here and in Google, but am not finding anything.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the manual? If not, perhaps [it's available on Yaesu's website](http://www.yaesu.com/indexVS.cfm?cmd=DisplayProducts&ProdCatID=102&encProdID=721B3F7D596827E0B37BD528EE1A56F1&DivisionID=65&isArchived=0).

Comment: I do, but it doesn't get into many details about the menu options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more digging I found the answer. SWR is an option on the meter display.  You can display ALC or power output or SWR or one of a few other options by pressing the "Scope" button a few times and changing the Meter option.

Comment: Good! Since you found the solution, you should mark your own answer as accepted. Otherwise, the system will automatically keep pushing this question to the top.